# If I order GRE score reports before my Subject GRE score is available, will schools receive it?

Tags: united-states, gre

I am planning to send both General and Subject GRE scores to some universities using the "order additional score reports" option. My subject GRE score is not available yet. It would take twenty more days. After selecting both of my GRE scores, it shows that one test score is being sent. I want to know if my subject GRE score will also be sent once it becomes available or do I have to spend $27 again just to send the subject GRE score to those universities?

Comment: Have you asked the GRE people?